# has_many through self referential association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-many-through, self-reference

I want to (as an example) create a `has_many` association to all posts by friends of a person,  something like `has_many :remote_posts` to give me something like `person > friends > person > posts`.

..here is how I would go about it

```
script/generate model post title:string person_id:integer
script/generate model friendship person_id:integer friend_id:integer
script/generate model person name:string
```

---

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  has_many :friendships, :foreign_key => 'friend_id'
  has_many :people, :through => :friendships
  has_many :remote_posts, :class_name => 'Post', :through => :people, :source => :posts
end
class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
  #also has a 'friend_id' to see who the friendship is aimed at
end
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
end
```

---

```
# generate some people and friends
{'frank' => ['bob','phil'], 'bob' => ['phil']}.each {|k,v|
  v.each {|f| 
    Friendship.create(
      :person_id => Person.find_or_create_by_name(f).id,
      :friend_id => Person.find_or_create_by_name(k).id
    )
  }
}
# generate some posts
Person.all.each {|p|
  p.posts.create({:title => "Post by #{p.name}"})
}
```

---

Now,

```
Person.first.friendships  # ..works
Person.first.people  # (friends) ..works
Person.first.posts # ..works
Person.first.remote_posts #....
```

...and I get this error..

`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: people.person_id: SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts"  INNER JOIN "people" ON "posts".person_id = "people".id    WHERE (("people".person_id = 1))`

Aside from the foreign key error - seems like the friendships association isn't coming into play at all.  I was thinking that this might be because of the `:source => :posts`,  since the `posts` association would come into it twice.

I could write some finder sql (and that is what I have working at the moment),  though I'd sooner do it this way.

Any ideas of how to get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

In the `FriendShip` class, add:

```
has_many :posts, :through => :person
```

and in the `Person` class, change the remote_posts to:

```
has_many :remote_posts, :class_name => 'Post',
         :through => :friendships, :source => :person
```

Comment: JRL, That is way better!

Unfortunately it still doesn't work completely (perhaps due to an unrelated problem)

when you call: 
   Person.find_by_name('frank').remote_posts

..it fires off this SQL:
   SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" INNER JOIN "friendships" ON "posts".id = "friendships".person_id WHERE (("friendships".friend_id = 2)) 

It should have joined on posts.person_id instead of posts.id (so it returns the posts with the same id as your friends)

I tried putting in some :foreign_key's,  but doesn't seem to work.

Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Damnit - I should have known it wouldn't format properly..  Problem is that person#remote_posts uses post.id instead of post.person_id - but I think that's 80% there!

Answer (score 0):

How about a nested `has_many :through` relationship. This seems to work for me:

```
class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :friend, :class_name => 'Person'
  has_many :posts, :through => :friend, :source => :posts
end
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  has_many :friendships, :foreign_key => 'friend_id'
  has_many :people, :through => :friendships
  has_many :remote_posts, :through => :friendships, :source => :posts
end
```

Note: this requires this [`nested_has_many_through` plugin](http://github.com/ianwhite/nested_has_many_through). (Note: direct linking to github repos seems to be broken... but that repo is there despite the error message.)